# Unable to store web notifications received in service worker in indexDB

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I am using Firebase cloud messaging. I am using the below sample link. 
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js

Notifications are received. I want to store notifications in indexDB in service worker.

```
var setupDone = false;
var storage = {
    setup: function() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var request = indexedDB.open(notificationdb, 1);
            request.onsuccess = function (e) {
                setupDone = true;
                var db = e.target.result;
                storage.db = db;
                resolve();
            };
            request.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {
                storage.db = e.target.result;
                if (storage.db.objectStoreNames.contains('notifications')) {
                    storage.db.deleteObjectStore('notifications');
                }
                storage.db.createObjectStore('notifications', {
                    keyPath: '_id'
                });
            };
        });
    },

    transaction: function (mode) {
        var trans = storage.db.transaction('notifications', mode);
        return trans.objectStore('notifications');
    },

    add: function (notification) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var request = 
            storage.transaction('readwrite').put(notification);
            request.onsuccess = function () {
                resolve(notification);
            };
            request.onerror = function() {
                reject();
            };
        });
    }
};
 messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
       var notification = payload.notification;
       var data = {};
       data.title = notification.title;
       data.message = notification.body;
       data._id = getUniqueId();
      data.time = Date.now();
      if (!setupDone) {
        storage.setup().then(function() {
            storage.add(data);
        });
       } else {
        storage.add(data);
       }
     return 
      self.registration.showNotification(notification.title,notification.body);
  });
```

But it is not stored in indexDB. Database is created. But data is not stored. Please help if anything is wrong here.

Comment: may be if you'll explain what is behind  ` //code to store in indexDB.` it will be easier to find the issue..

Comment: Are you setting the `notification` field server-side when you create the message? If so, as per this issue, the setBackgroundMessageHandler is ignored: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/71#issuecomment-258872970

Comment: No problem with receiving notification.Only insertion into indexDB is not working