# Use firebase-messaging-sw.js to sync data in BackgroundMessageHandler ReactApp

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I think this question was already asked and some proposals were done:
[Store data in Background Message](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/111)
[Unable to store web notifications received in service worker in indexDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45451648/unable-to-store-web-notifications-received-in-service-worker-in-indexdb)
Unfortunately, I still couldn't find a concrete example of how to do it (or if it's indeed possible).
AFAIK the local storage or cookies are not available in `firebase-messaging-sw.js` and the only available approach is to use `indexDB`.
Goal: To have the option to handle the data which received in `messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler` and store it in local storage. 
Approach: Store the data in `indexDB` when the web app in the background, when the web app becomes visible replace the data to local storage.

Our app is based on `React`,`Redux`.
My knowledge of web development is very limited so feel free to correct me. 

[Firebaase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code sample to use indexDB in `firebase-messaging-sw.js`

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(payload => {
        try {
            function logerr(err) {
                console.log('Database erroor: ',err);
            }
            function connectDB(f) {
                const request = exports.indexedDB.open('lone', 1);
                request.onerror = logerr;
                request.onsuccess = function() {
                    f(request.result);
                };
                request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
                    e.currentTarget.result.createObjectStore('Table1', { keyPath: 'ssn' });
                    connectDB(f);
                };
            }
                connectDB(db => {
                    const transition = db.transaction(['Table1'], 'readwrite');
                    const objectStore = transition.objectStore('data');
                    const customerData = {
                        ssn: '444-44-4444',                                                
                        payload: payload.data.payload,
                    };
                    const objectStoreRequest = objectStore.add(customerData);

                    objectStoreRequest.onerror = logerr;
                    objectStoreRequest.onsuccess = function() {
                        return objectStoreRequest.result;
                    };
                });

                const notificationTitle = 'Title';
                const notificationOptions = {
                    body: message,
                    icon: 'favicon.png',
                };

                return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);

        } catch (e) {
            console.log('error', e);
        }
    });
})(this);
```